# Fluent mapping inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have an issue I don't know the best solution for. Hopefully someone here can help =)

What I'm trying to solve:
We have to type of users in a system, person and organization.
I want to have a shared login table for the two (ie the user probably won't know which type of user they are, they just relate to username and password).
So I've created a login table for usernames and passwords. But I need to know who the login is connected to, so I need a reference to either person or organization.

Consider the following classes (simplified):

```
public class Login
{
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
}

public class LoginPerson : Login
{
    public Person Person {get;set;}
}

public class LoginOrg : Login
{
    public Organization Organization {get;set;}
}

public class Person
{
    public LoginPerson LoginPerson {get;set;}
    //Lots of other properties. Removed for simplicity
}

public class Organization
{
    public LoginOrg LoginOrg {get;set;}
    //Lots of other properties. Removed for simplicity
}
```

The person configuration is set up as follows:

```
public class PersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
    {
        public PersonConfiguration()
        {
            HasRequired(p => p.LoginPerson).WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.Person);
        }
    }
```

First of all, this doesn't work. I get an exception saying 
"System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException: System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.."
So my first question is why doesn't this work?
My second question is: which strategy is best suited for this kind of inheritance? TPT, TPH or TPC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my exception was to set up the correct configuration ;-)
PersonConfiguration didn't need to include any configuration for the LoginPerson property. I added a LoginPersonConfiguration ->

```
public class LoginPersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<LoginPerson>
{
    public LoginPersonConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("LoginPerson");
        HasKey(l => l.Id);
        HasRequired(l => l.Person).WithOptional(p => p.LoginPerson).Map(t => t.MapKey("PersonId")); 
    }
}
```

And I also had to add the  Login to the DbContext class

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }
}
```

When it comes to which strategy is best, I have decided to go for TPT.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, none of your entities have keys.  You need a primary key to make them work.  EF uses a convention to do this, which is the class name plus Id at the end, like PersonId, or you key be explicit with an attribute of `[Key]`

Second, your model is confusing and fairly circular.  And without primary keys, there's no way to to create associations.

I'm confused about why you have a member that is a LoginPerson in a Person object, and the same for an Organization?  In any event, you really need to rethink this model and figure out what your keys are.

Comment: Sorry about not including the primary keys. I removed them when I simplified the classes. All classes has an Id column which is a PK.    The circular reference is intentional, as they are navigational properties.  However, I solved the exception issue. And my second question can be answered by google =)